# Pandas merged cell issue when reading from excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

So I have a xls file with some weird style but there's nothing I can do about it so I just need to parse it.

[image]

As you can see I have some merged cells. What I want to do is fill the empty values for the merged cells ("ffill") but also keep the empty cells like they are.

Something like this

`EIM, C,NI1 Enescu_Ioan,      EIM, S,NI11,Enescu_Ioan
 EIM, C,NI1 Enescu_Ioan,      Empty
 EIM, C,NI1 Enescu_Ioan       EIM, S,NI11,Enescu_Ioan
 EIM, C,NI1,Enescu_Ioan       Empty`

The way I'm loading the file right now is this.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile("data/file.xls")
df = xl.parse(0, header=None)
```

I've also tried to open the file like this and access the merged cells but I get an empty list.

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("data/file.xls")
book.sheet_by_index(0).merged_cells # This is empty []
```

Is there any way I could achieve this? Thanks!

EDIT

There might be some confusions regarding the question so I'll try to explain better. The attached image is a subset of a larger file where the columns may appear in different order. What I'm trying to achieve is a way of differentiating between merged cells NAN values (in a merged cell only the first column has a value, the rest are all nan) and empty cells NAN.

Comment: Did you try pandas read_excel?? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: @MahendraSingh Yes, I get the same output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to find a fix

```
def read_excel(path):
    excel = None
    if path.endswith('xlsx'):
        excel = pd.ExcelFile(xlrd.open_workbook(path), engine='xlrd')
    elif path.endswith('xls'):
        excel = pd.ExcelFile(xlrd.open_workbook(path, formatting_info=True), engine='xlrd')
    else:
        raise ValueError("Could not read this type of data")
    return excel

def parse_excel(excel_file):
    sheet_0 = excel_file.book.sheet_by_index(0)
    df = excel_file.parse(0, header=None)
    return sheet_0, df

def fill_merged_na(sheet, dataframe):
    for e in sheet.merged_cells:
        rl, rh, cl, ch = e
        base_value = sheet.cell_value(rl, cl)
        dataframe.iloc[rl:rh, cl:ch] = base_value
    return dataframe
```

Some of the important bits are opening the excel file with the formatting_info set to True in order to also read formatting such as merged cells and the fill_merged_na function that fills only the merged nan values but leaves the initial empty cells as they were.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: xlrd does't support xlsx now. This will give the error: `XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported`.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to easily do this with openpyxl?
Right now I'm doing it manually using `Worksheet.merged_cells` to determine which cells are merged, and applying the value to each of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the DataFrame looks like if you do `df = pd.read_excel('path')`

```
print(df)

                     Col1                     Col2
0  EIM, C,NI1 Enescu_Ioan  EIM, S,NI11,Enescu_Ioan
1                     NaN                      NaN
2                     NaN  EIM, S,NI11,Enescu_Ioan
3                     NaN                      NaN
```

Now, fill the value from the first entry of merged cell:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

And use `pandas.DataFrame.replace` to change the `NaN` with blanks:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].replace(np.nan,'')
```

An example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['EIM, C,NI1 Enescu_Ioan',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 
                   'Col2' : ['EIM, S,NI11,Enescu_Ioan',np.nan,'EIM, S,NI11,Enescu_Ioan',np.nan]})

print(df)

                     Col1                     Col2
0  EIM, C,NI1 Enescu_Ioan  EIM, S,NI11,Enescu_Ioan
1                     NaN                      NaN
2                     NaN  EIM, S,NI11,Enescu_Ioan
3                     NaN                      NaN

df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].fillna(method = 'ffill')
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].replace(np.nan,'')
print(df)
                     Col1                     Col2
0  EIM, C,NI1 Enescu_Ioan  EIM, S,NI11,Enescu_Ioan
1  EIM, C,NI1 Enescu_Ioan                         
2  EIM, C,NI1 Enescu_Ioan  EIM, S,NI11,Enescu_Ioan
3  EIM, C,NI1 Enescu_Ioan
```

Comment: Yeah, that works in this case but the columns can appear in any order and this was just a small subset of the file. What I need is a method to distinguish between merged cells nan and empty cells nan.

Comment: This was as per your expected output, please edit your question to include complete problem and expected output, also as per my understanding pandas returns `NaN` while reading any sort of empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

I updated @radulescu-petru solution to work with openpyxl

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

def read_excel(path):
    return openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

def parse_excel(excel_file, sheet_name):
    sheet = excel_file[sheet_name]
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=None)
    return sheet, df
    
def fill_merged_na(sheet, dataframe):
    for merged_cell_range in sheet.merged_cells:
        # Get the start cell's row and column indices
        min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = openpyxl.utils.cell.range_boundaries(str(merged_cell_range))
        # Get the value from the first cell
        base_value = df.iat[min_row-1, min_col-1]
        dataframe.iloc[min_row-1:max_row, min_col-1:max_col] = base_value
    return dataframe

excel_file = read_excel('some_file.xlsx')
sheet, df = parse_excel(excel_file, 'sheet A')
df_filled = fill_merged_na(sheet, df)
df_filled.head()
```

Comment: I think the var `df` is not defined in the function fill_merged_na