# How to differentiate Excel merged cells from blank cells in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have a table on Excel like the image below: 
[image]

How can I differentiate the blank cells from the blank merged cells on python (pandas)? I want to put the value "X" on "**1i**" but I cannot use ffill because I don't want to put values on "**1a**" or "**1b**" for example.

Note that it is just an example and I have several numbers of tables with this same situation where we have a merged cell with an "X".

Another table example:
[image]

Comment: I assume this table with merged cells comes from Excel? Is the merged cell an index of some sort? Can you try the  `index_col` option to `pd.read_excel()`? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70841452/530160)

Comment: Hi Nick! This tables comes from excel and works like a matrix to identify information in another documents, the problem is sometimes the information comes merged like the column 1 and sometimes like the column 5, and the location of this merged information is random. Pandas cannot identify by itself when I have merged data and just copy/paste the text on all the cells?

Comment: Pandas doesn't really have a way to represent a merged cell. It's something that doesn't appear in any of the other formats that Pandas can read/write. If `index_col` doesn't work, another idea would be to use `xlrd` to read the file, because that *can* understand merged cells. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631965/pandas-merged-cell-issue-when-reading-from-excel

Comment: That was my fear  Thank you very much Nick!

Comment: But not XLRD if its a `.xlsx` file. XLRD only reads the original propriety Excel `.xls` format for some time.